# Get or create unique node (create) ocurre Error 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: rest, post, neo4j

When i use chrome extension Postman test ["17.11.1. Get or create unique node (create)"](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-unique-indexes.html)
I got some exceptions:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <title>Error 415 Unsupported Media Type</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 415</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /db/data/index/node/people. Reason:

        <pre>    Unsupported Media Type</pre>
    </p>
    <hr />
    <i>
        <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
    </i>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</body>
```

my test parameters:

```
http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/index/node/people?uniqueness=get_or_create
```

json data

```
{
    "key" : "name",
    "value" : "Tobias",
    "properties" : {
        "name" : "Tobias",
        "sequence" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `Content-Type` set to `application/json`?

Comment: yeah,I have setted to content type to "json"

Comment: Have you done both? Are they both correct, including the slash direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah,I find the problem,my test neo4j's release (1.8.2),but I refer to neo4j manual [1.9.M05](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/)
neo4j manual's version 1.8.2 
[Create a unique node in an index](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-unique-indexes.html) 
post url:`POST http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/index/node/people?unique`
but neo4j manual's version 1.9.m05
[Create a unique node in an index](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-unique-indexes.html)
post url:`POST http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/index/node/people?uniqueness=get_or_create`
so I get Unsupported Media Type errors.

Comment: Yes, that was changed between releases, so you need to take the correct one for your version.